# How to scale a svg polygon dynamically to fit into 24X 24 size?

Tags: javascript, svg, resize, scaling

My sample code is

```
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin"
                                 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <polygon points="150,75 258,137.5 258,262.5 150,325 42,262.6 42,137.5"/>
                    </svg>
```

the polygon points will be loaded from service and i want to resize and scale the polygon to fit into 24 x 24 area.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by 24 X 24 area ?

Comment: we need to resize the polygon and display it as a icon in 24x 24 pixels

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the values from the `getBBox()` function and update your `viewBox` with those.

```js
var myPath = document.getElementById("p1")
var mySvg = document.getElementById("s1")
var b = myPath.getBBox();
mySvg.setAttribute("viewBox", [b.x, b.y, b.width, b.height].join(" "));
```

```html
<svg width="24" height="24" id="s1">
  <polygon id="p1" points="150,75 258,137.5 258,262.5 150,325 42,262.6 42,137.5"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: however if i have a child inside a polygon then the getBBox(); is always giving me zero ,any hack for this

Comment: What do you mean "a child inside a polygon"?

Comment: a polygon enclosed inside of other one.

Comment: You haven't made things any clearer because you have used almost exactly the same words :)  I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: i did a work around similar to bbox method and now its working fine.somehow the polygon if it enclosed by any ther polygon ,the bbox method is returning zero.

Comment: no no ,i am saying i got a solution by writing a method similar to svg bbox.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As your points are dynamic. You can dynamically calculate the polygon dimension to set the height and width of viewport

```js
var myPath = document.getElementById("p1")
var w = myPath.getBoundingClientRect().width;
var h = myPath.getBoundingClientRect().height;
document.getElementById("s1").setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 " + h +  " " + w);
```

```html
<svg width="24" height="24" id="s1"
                                 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <polygon id="p1" points="150,75 258,137.5 258,262.5 150,325 42,262.6 42,137.5"/>
                    </svg>
```

Comment: I tried setting viewbox to the getBoundingClientRect() width and height respectively but sometimes the polygon is either cropped or not at all visible in the viewbox if the points of polygon are higher than viewbox.

Comment: This is incorrect. You should be using `getBBox()` not `getBoundingClientRect`. Also the `w` and `h` variables are the wrong way round in the viewBox.